# how to apply an ajax/json search filter when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am displaying items on a page using json, I also have a search filter with a text box and button I got working so when the item details are included and entered it filters the items to match the search from the user input. Below is the search form and also the js:

```
<div class="container search-container">
<form class="form-search form-inline"> 
    <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search"> <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 
</form>
```

Calling the json:

```
$.getJSON('iproducts.json',function(products){
var output = "";
$.each(products.appleitems, function(i, product) { 

    output += 
        "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3\"><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-footer'><h4 class='text-center'>"  
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id 
        + "</h4></div>" + "<img src ='" + products.appleitems[i].Imgpath + "'  style='width:100%;height:250px; display: block;' id='appleinfo_" 
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id + 
        "' /><p class='lead text-justify'>" + products.appleitems[i].Information
        + "</p><div class='panel-footer'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button></div></div></div>";
    });

$("#container").html(output);
});
```

filtering the json:

```
$('.form-search').on('submit',function(){return false;});

$('.form-search .btn').on('click', function(e){ 
var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase(); 
regex = new RegExp(query, "i");
$.getJSON('iproducts.json', function (products) {
    var output;
    $.each(products.appleitems, function (i, product) {

        if (product.Product_id.search(regex) != -1) {
    output += 
        "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3\"><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-footer'><h4 class='text-center'>"  
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id 
        + "</h4></div>" + "<img src ='" + products.appleitems[i].Imgpath + "'  style='width:100%;height:250px; display: block;' id='appleinfo_" 
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id + 
        "' /><p class='lead text-justify'>" + products.appleitems[i].Information
        + "</p><div class='panel-footer'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button></div></div></div>";
        }
            $('#container').html(output);

            console.log(products.appleitems[i]);
        }
    )
});
```

I would like to make my search more dynamic, I want the search to narrow down when the user is actually typing in the text box instead of a .click function. I have been trying a few key up methods but have got none of these to work. Does anyone know how I can apply this to my search instead of using a .click function?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the keypress event

```
$('.search-query').on('keypress',function(){
  //get the json
  //filter it
});
```

Comment: This seems correct answer to me but I guess there must be some timespan between users typing is stopped and making `http` request..Making `api` call for each key press does not seem that optimal..

Comment: better put that json in localsotrage at page load and then search the localstorage if you don't want multiple ajax events

Comment: That seems bad option as server data may update between storing it in localstorage and making `http` request..It is not about personal choice..Its about performance..

Comment: add a modifed parameter to the localsorage and do a ajax to test if json is updated,if updated do ajax for the ubdated content

Comment: `LocalStorage` is not applicable here. There can be crores of records to be searched..And that is the reason I am asking to avoid unnecessary requests and DB operation. Every browser has some limit for localStorage storage..

Comment: than you need to do the sorting on the server and serv a limited number of items with ajax

Comment: Sorting for what ? And limited number of records ? What is user is looking for something specific which is not there in _limited records_ ?

Comment: the user searches using other keywords or you create some type of navigation serving only the first set and ajax for the next page sets

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/change/ is the correct way to do this.

Use like `$('.search-query').on('change', function(e){ ...`

Comment: Got this working guys on the key up  -   $('.search-query').keyup(function(e){ 
 var output="";